# How to import two different classes with the same name

Tags: java, android

I tried to import the following:

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
```

But it says a type named `LayoutParams` has already been imported.

Comment: Wrongly marked as duplicate. Checked the link all the answers are python related.

Comment: One solution that I'm not sure is mentioned in the duplicate link is to use `import android.widget.LinearLayout` and `import android.widget.RelativeLayout`, and then in your code, you can do `LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1` and `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2`. This is a unique case because these are both nested classes

Comment: android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout = new  Use the reference directly in the code like android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(); 

    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutprm = new android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams()

Comment: @AbhijitPritam you're wrong, the person who is asking just used a python code as an example for comparison, but everything is about java, even the question itself